# Views count for posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a social network coded with Ruby on Rails 3.2.
I've created a table PostView in order to count post views by user. It has with the following columns : post_id, user_id, created_at. The idea is to store a new entry in that table every time a user sees a post (ideally adding the condition that he has not already seen it in the last 6 hours).

My problem is that I would like to do it when user loads its news feed. As many posts are loaded at the same time, I would like to do one request that will create an entry for each post viewed (I definitely don't want to do a request in a loop)

Any thoughts ?

Comment: your question is not clear at all

Comment: I just hope you're using redis

Answer (score 2):

If i understant your question correctly then what you need is put your code in controller like

```
def show
 @post = Post.all
 #next you need to do a view count so create a new method
 @post_view =  PostView.create_new_post_view(@post, current_user)
end
```

in the Post view model

```
def self.create_new_post_view(post, user)
 post.each do |p|
 # put your 6 hour logic here as you have to loop through it because your logic must be valid against each post. so against each post you have to validate your logic.
 end
end
```

Comment: You've understood my question. So you're suggesting me to do a ".save!" in a loop ? Is that a correct way to do it ?

Comment: as you have real time checking against each post then there is no other way. no it is not the ideal way to do it as it will make multiple db connection call. instead of making it a model method create a procedure for it so your number of db call will be decreased.

Comment: @titibouboul you can check the link for how to create procedure in rails 3 http://programminginrubyonrails.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-write-store-procedure-in-rails-3.html

Comment: I don't really understand how procedures work. I'm thinking that I could store all data, and check the "6 hours" condition after. What would it be in that case (ie. same process with no condition)?

Comment: no procedure means mysql store procedure. sql inside the databse.

Comment: Ok thanks - so I've used your method. I think I won't accept your answer because I would like to see if there is a way to do it using RoR logic, and I'm sure there must be one :)

Comment: sure @titibouboul. if there is something else it will be good for me to learn :)